# How to deal with Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code on FBReactNativeSpec?

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm having issues creating new project in react-native.

Xcode builds every of my projects but new ones.

I've tried many solutions found on stackOverflow and on random websites but the build always fails with :

FBReactNativeSpec
Uncategorized
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Here's some of the solution I've tried so far:

- re-started computer
- Deleted repo and cloned it again
- Tried on may brand new RN projects
- Re-installed pods
- Updated pods
- Re-installed cocoapods
- removing nvm
- Removed everything related to Xcode on my computer and re-installed it.

The projects build on my colleague computer.

I'm using a MBP 2,6 GHz Intel Core i7 6 cœurs

Xcode version is 13.4.1

Here's the script :

```
    pushd "$PODS_ROOT/../" > /dev/null
RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT=$(pwd)
popd >/dev/null

export RCT_SCRIPT_RN_DIR=${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/../..
export RCT_SCRIPT_LIBRARY_NAME=FBReactNativeSpec
export RCT_SCRIPT_OUTPUT_DIR=$RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT/build/generated/ios
export RCT_SCRIPT_LIBRARY_TYPE=modules
export RCT_SCRIPT_JS_SRCS_PATTERN=Native*.js
export RCT_SCRIPT_JS_SRCS_DIR=../../Libraries
export RCT_SCRIPT_CODEGEN_MODULE_DIR=.
export RCT_SCRIPT_CODEGEN_COMPONENT_DIR=react/renderer/components
export RCT_SCRIPT_FILE_LIST="[\"../../Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/NativeActionSheetManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/Alert/NativeAlertManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper.js\", \"../../Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedModule.js\", \"../../Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedTurboModule.js\", \"../../Libraries/AppState/NativeAppState.js\", \"../../Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js\", \"../../Libraries/Blob/NativeBlobModule.js\", \"../../Libraries/Blob/NativeFileReaderModule.js\", \"../../Libraries/BugReporting/NativeBugReporting.js\", \"../../Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/NativeAccessibilityInfo.js\", \"../../Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/NativeAccessibilityManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/Components/Clipboard/NativeClipboard.js\", \"../../Libraries/Components/DatePickerAndroid/NativeDatePickerAndroid.js\", \"../../Libraries/Components/Keyboard/NativeKeyboardObserver.js\", \"../../Libraries/Components/Sound/NativeSoundManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/Components/StatusBar/NativeStatusBarManagerAndroid.js\", \"../../Libraries/Components/StatusBar/NativeStatusBarManagerIOS.js\", \"../../Libraries/Components/ToastAndroid/NativeToastAndroid.js\", \"../../Libraries/Core/NativeExceptionsManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/Core/SegmentFetcher/NativeSegmentFetcher.js\", \"../../Libraries/Core/Timers/NativeTiming.js\", \"../../Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js\", \"../../Libraries/EventEmitter/__mocks__/NativeEventEmitter.js\", \"../../Libraries/HeapCapture/NativeJSCHeapCapture.js\", \"../../Libraries/Image/NativeImageEditor.js\", \"../../Libraries/Image/NativeImageLoaderAndroid.js\", \"../../Libraries/Image/NativeImageLoaderIOS.js\", \"../../Libraries/Image/NativeImagePickerIOS.js\", \"../../Libraries/Image/NativeImageStoreAndroid.js\", \"../../Libraries/Image/NativeImageStoreIOS.js\", \"../../Libraries/Interaction/NativeFrameRateLogger.js\", \"../../Libraries/Linking/NativeIntentAndroid.js\", \"../../Libraries/Linking/NativeLinkingManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/Modal/NativeModalManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/NativeComponent/NativeComponentRegistry.js\", \"../../Libraries/NativeComponent/NativeComponentRegistryUnstable.js\", \"../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeAnimationsDebugModule.js\", \"../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeDevMenu.js\", \"../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeDevSettings.js\", \"../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeDeviceEventManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeDialogManagerAndroid.js\", \"../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeLogBox.js\", \"../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeRedBox.js\", \"../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeSourceCode.js\", \"../../Libraries/Network/NativeNetworkingAndroid.js\", \"../../Libraries/Network/NativeNetworkingIOS.js\", \"../../Libraries/Performance/NativeJSCSamplingProfiler.js\", \"../../Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/NativePermissionsAndroid.js\", \"../../Libraries/PushNotificationIOS/NativePushNotificationManagerIOS.js\", \"../../Libraries/ReactNative/NativeHeadlessJsTaskSupport.js\", \"../../Libraries/ReactNative/NativeI18nManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/ReactNative/NativeUIManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/Settings/NativeSettingsManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/Share/NativeShareModule.js\", \"../../Libraries/Storage/NativeAsyncLocalStorage.js\", \"../../Libraries/Storage/NativeAsyncSQLiteDBStorage.js\", \"../../Libraries/TurboModule/samples/NativeSampleTurboModule.js\", \"../../Libraries/Utilities/NativeAppearance.js\", \"../../Libraries/Utilities/NativeDevLoadingView.js\", \"../../Libraries/Utilities/NativeDevSplitBundleLoader.js\", \"../../Libraries/Utilities/NativeDeviceInfo.js\", \"../../Libraries/Utilities/NativeJSDevSupport.js\", \"../../Libraries/Utilities/NativePlatformConstantsAndroid.js\", \"../../Libraries/Utilities/NativePlatformConstantsIOS.js\", \"../../Libraries/Vibration/NativeVibration.js\", \"../../Libraries/WebSocket/NativeWebSocketModule.js\"]"

SCRIPT_PHASES_SCRIPT="$RCT_SCRIPT_RN_DIR/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.sh"
/bin/sh -c "$SCRIPT_PHASES_SCRIPT"
```

One question occurs to me : what's the ${pwd} variable in the second line ?

EDIT : As a troubleshooting step, I tried to start a new project with an older version of React-Native (0.66.1), and it works fine.

Comment: `pwd` is the current directory (from the script's point of view). If you're wondering what it is, print it out (with echo).

Comment: @JSharles did you try removing `Podfile.lock` and running `pod install`?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Yes, I did. It was one of the first step I took.

Comment: @JSharles Did you find the problem?

Comment: @DavidSmith As far as I remember, I think I had the issue with a particular version of RN (the latest back then).. since then the issue does not occur anymore. What's your version ?